# Differentiating lines in chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I'm wondering if there is a way to differentiate multiple lines in a chart (using Windows Forms Chart) through means other than different colors. In Excel you can make small triangles or other shapes appear on different lines in a graph, and I was wondering if you could do something similar in C# for sets of 3 or more lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the shape of the marker ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.markerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), for point-type charts:

```
chart1.Series["MySeries"].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square;
```

You can also set background colors and gradients / hatching ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.backgradientstyle(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.backgradientstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) for bar-type charts:

```
chart1.Series["MySeries"].BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;
```

You can also specify line thickness and/or style for line-type charts:

```
chart1.Series["MySeries"].BorderWidth = 4;
chart1.Series["MySeries"].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```